# Accessibility concerns in overriding the browser's native text-selector with CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, accessibility

In some designs for web projects, I've seen that the designer wants the browser's native text-selector to be customized following the Design System. For example, by changing the `background` and `color` of a text when it is selected. I'm not sure about the accessibility issues this can cause. My first take is that if the custom CSS matches the requirements of WCAG 1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum) it would be OK, as it happens with custom outlines for focus. However, I'm not sure about the secondary issues that this could cause to users with special contrast configurations in their system and browser.

**1. Would overriding the browser's native text-selector with CSS be compliant with WCAG?**

**2. Can it cause other accessibility issues beyond what WCAG covers?**

In my SASS code, it looks like this: (from [this CSS trick](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/))

```scss
body *::selection {
    color: $white;
    background: $primary-color-main; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
  
body *::-moz-selection {
    color: $white;
    background: $primary-color-main; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```

A minimal reproducible example (without variables):
*This code changes the text-selector for all elements that are recurrent descendants of the body in any HTML code.*

```css
body *::selection {
    color: white;
    background: black; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
  
body *::-moz-selection {
    color: white;
    background: black; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```

Comment: _"However, I'm not sure about the secondary issues that this could cause to users with special contrast configurations in their system and browser."_ - would make little difference to when you formatted a text with that same color and background-color to begin with, independent from any user selection, no? As long as the contrast requirements from WCAG 1.4.3 are fulfilled, what does it matter how the text _got_ into that "state"?

Comment: 1. You can manually check contrast between any two colors using  https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/. 2. As a web developer, you should only care about respecting the current standards. If you come across an issue/case which you think is not adequately covered by the standards you should open a ticket with them and go through the process of altering the standards. Assuming the process is successful, as a web developer, you should only care about implementing the change after it was adopted.

Comment: I'm familiar with WCAG contrast requirements. My doubt is if this kind of overriding can interfere with the user: included in any WCAG criteria beyond contrast (even AAA) or beyond WCAG in any other ways to be aware of it.

Comment: Ref: *"issues that this could cause to users with special contrast configurations on their system and browser"*. Let's say I have a system (or browser) which renders every single pixel as black, effectively resulting in a contrast ratio of `0`. Are you trying to write (S)CSS which would prevent my system from rendering every single pixel black? How? The point being: browser or system settings/configs are outside the scope of your concern. Your website is not supposed to fix/alter them. Not to mention it lacks access to them. You can't fix something you can't read.

Comment: For example, regarding focus outline instead of text-selector: if you use the browser's native outline you give the user the chance to customize that outline for every page following their needs. However, if a custom outline is set up using CSS the user won't have that chance.

Comment: @tao, a nitpick but the contrast ratio of black on black (or white on white or red on red, etc) is `1:1`, not `0:1`.

Comment: Fair point, @slugo :)

Answer (score 1):

Custom selection styles are compatible with WCAG criteria, as long as you fulfill the general requirements for color contrast and so on.

That said, custom selection styles could still be an accessibility issue. Users sometimes specify their own selection styles to fit their own needs. Additionally, users may be confused by changes to the expected appearance of selected text.

[MDN has a little more info about selection accessibility.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection#accessibility_concerns)

Comment: I had not seen that information in MDN. Really useful!

Answer (score 1):

Customizing the text selection color is perfectly fine as long as you follow [1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-minimum), as you noted.  I've seen custom selection colors done for branding purposes and it can look really good.

There aren't any other WCAG issues with having a custom selection style but one thing you might want to check is if you turn on the OS's high contrast mode, whether PC or Mac, can you still see/read your text when it's selected?  If you can't, it's not a strict WCAG failure but would certainly be a usability issue.

Also, having a custom selection style does not preclude the user from having their own customizations.  I do this myself.  I have a style sheet associated with my various browsers so that my customizations show up on any website I visit.  I have `!important` in my CSS so that it will override whatever the site tries to do so I could still have my own selection style no matter how you tried to set it.